# Selecting an object results in double outline and object doesn't move

Tags: object-mode, select

When I select an object in object mode the object now gets outlined with 2 orange lines as opposed to just one.  Moving the object moves the outline and not the geometry.  To move the geometry it seems I now have to choose 'Set Origin'.  How do I get Blender back into normal object selection and transform mode?

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue caused by an unsupported GPU (more likely), or out of date drivers (less likely). Check here to make sure your GPU is supported, and if it is, update the drivers. - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: You have saved me hours of grief.  I had installed Blender for my son and it was working for a couple of days when this happened.  I had assumed that he changed a setting and I was hunting through all of the options for selecting and transforms (I don't know Blender so I was struggling).  I did have to start Blender on the machine using the GPU workaround but wasn't suspicious of that since it seemed to be working fine.  Thanks for your help!